# android - Pass parameters into Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fileinputstream

I am using AsyncTask for sending files to the server.the Asynctask is a different class file not inside the MainActivity.the problem what i am facing is when i write AsyncTask inside the MainActivity class. everything works great. but when i write different java class and send parameter by accessing this class from MainActivity  i get these errors

```
02-23 01:06:46.995: I/System.out(1191): path is[Ljava.lang.String;@b1dccd40
02-23 01:06:47.125: E/Debug(1191): error: /[Ljava.lang.String;@b1dccd40: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-23 01:06:47.125: E/Debug(1191): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /[Ljava.lang.String;@b1dccd40: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

here is my code

```
public class ASync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    protected String doInBackground(String... path) {
         System.out.println("path is" + path);
         HttpURLConnection conn = null;
         DataOutputStream dos = null;
         DataInputStream inStream = null;
         String lineEnd = "\r\n";
         String twoHyphens = "--";
         String boundary =  "*****";
         int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
         byte[] buffer;
         int maxBufferSize = 4*1024*1024;
         String responseFromServer = "";
         String urlString = "http://path";
         try
         {
   /*----- i think this line is causing an error */
       FileInputStream fileInputStream =  new FileInputStream(new File(path.toString()) );
       /**----/       
             // open a URL connection to the Servlet
          URL url = new URL(urlString);
          // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
          conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
          // Allow Inputs
          conn.setDoInput(true);
          // Allow Outputs
          conn.setDoOutput(true);
          // Don't use a cached copy.
          conn.setUseCaches(false);
          // Use a post method.
          conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
          conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
          conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
          dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
          dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
          dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + path + "\"" + lineEnd);
          dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
          // create a buffer of maximum size
          bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
          bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
          buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
          // read file and write it into form...
          bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
          while (bytesRead > 0)
          {
           dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
           bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
           bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
           bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
          }
          // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
          dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
          dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
          // close streams
          Log.e("Debug","File is written");
          fileInputStream.close();
          dos.flush();
          dos.close();
         }
         catch (MalformedURLException ex)
         {
              Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
         }
         catch (IOException ioe)
         {
              Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
         }
         //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
         try {
               inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
               String str;

               while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
               {
                    Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
               }
               inStream.close();

         }
         catch (IOException ioex){
              Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
         }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }

    }
```

the only difference between two classes (one if i write asyncTask class inside MainActivity and one if i write seperate class.java file) is this line

AsyncTask inside the MainActivity:(This code works fine)

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath) );
//calling and passing parameter  like it.  
 new ASync().execute(selectedPath );
```

AsyncTask in separate Java file(not working)

```
   FileInputStream fileInputStream =  new FileInputStream(new File(path.toString()) );
     //calling and passing parameter  like it. 
       AudioSync sync = new AudioSync(); 
      sync.execute(getPath(selectedPath);
```

might b parameter passing issue. Am i using `FileInputStream` in the right way and am i passing the parameters correctly? Please see the code snippet. thanks
please do tell me how can i make this code work by declaring in separate class.

Comment: why not you pass a simple string path as your asynctask parameter. Save the path in a string and check if the path is not null then pass else show some invalid path message..

Comment: also you can pass parameter into constructor  if you work with separate java class

Comment: @hello check my answer. you can implement this way

Comment: @RanjitPati path is not null. check my error snippet. in the first line i printed it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass Parameter into constructor of `AsyncTask` like:

```
new ASync(selectedPath).execute(selectedPath);
```

And implement your `AsyncTask` like:

```
public class ASync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
 String pathstr="";

 public ASync(String str){
  this.pathstr=str;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because it's accessing path the wrong way.

`doInBackground(Params... params)` uses [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). So basically this method is accepting an array, not a single variable.

If your method is `doInBackground(String... paths)`, you can get the first (and sometimes the only) path using `paths[0]`. You may want to check whether `paths` is `null` or not beforehand.